# Can the house limit be circumvented?

Tags: pc, viva-pinata

Appearently in Viva Piñata one can only build a limit amount of houses despite having loads of space left. Can this be changed somehow, maybe via a mod? It would really be nice to be able and build all pinata housings in one single big garden. Or at least some more than only half the space available...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the housing limit is not avoidable, and there are no mods to remove it.

Comment: accepted until proven wrong, though I guess that won't happen - damn, this game _could_ be nice if it weren't for all those limitations and ignorance of usability